# keep gtk window fixed on screen

Tags: linux, gtk, xlib, xserver

How you keep gtk window fixed on screen like a taskbar or keep some space like taskbar reserved for our gtk window, Do i need to write some WM plugin. if it helps my wm is metacity, and can you integrate gtk with xlib program, actually I was developing a basic WM and feels the need for both xlib and gtk, doing anything with gtk in my wm simply crashes it.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea. Leave such things to window managers. If you want to write a WM, learn a lot more about the standards governing them (ICCCM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-Client_Communication_Conventions_Manual and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints EWMH...)

Answer (score 1):

The [NetWM/EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2551529) protocol supports docks/taskbars via setting the `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE` property to `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already figured it out by sending xWM configure event "_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL" and intercepting it on the WM side